# TexLive fails with version mismatch message quoting version nr to be 2^64 - 1. Known bug?

Tags: texlive-2021

I installed MacTex2021 on an unsupported MacOS version, 10.13.6 (High Sierra), following the instructions on https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html for installing 2021 on unsupported OSX versions, among which High Sierra.

The install seems ok judging from the 'latex --version' response.

However, TexLive does not work, with the message:
"The repository at https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet has TeX Live 2021, but you have TeX Live 18446744073709551615 installed.  You need to switch repositories in order to continue."

Note that 18446744073709551615=$2^{64}$-1, the largest unsigned 64 bit number.

The message varies somewhat depending on the mirror.

This should be a known issue since I encountered it years ago with the 2015 version. Here's an email exchange on this:

Dear Richard

The problem is fixed by adding the file.

Many thanks!

Anton

On 13 Jun 2015, at 15:48, Richard Koch koch@uoregon.edu wrote:

There was a bug in TeX Live itself which breaks TeX Live Utility from
properly updating the release. Others on the list know more and should
also answer. Fixes are being considered. If the md5 sum is correct, you
got the release version and everything is up to date as of a few days ago.

Dick Koch

On Jun 13, 2015, at 2:33 AM, anton.van.oosten@gmail.com wrote:

Support requested by: Anton van Oosten
About:                TexLive fails to show udates
Computer:             Intel Imac 27" late 2012
MacOS X:              10.10.3 (14D136)
Installer problem:    no
.dmg version date:    Wednesday 10 June 2015 04:25
.dmg file size:       2.678.205.589
Downloaded from:      http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg
Application problem:  no
Which application:

Question:

An hour ago I downloaded and installed the latest MacTex.
TexLive states that this is version "18446744073709551615",
which does not match "2015" on the update server.
Thus TexLive cannot download updates.
I checked the md5, it is identical to the one listed at https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html.

---

Crash report:

Exception Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Description: Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3dc3df3b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff64f96942 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3dc43b22 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3fd8c9f0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b171054 -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 327
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b170e61 -[NSCell setStringValue:] + 43
6   TeX Live Utility                    0x000000010e273b73 -[TLMAddressTextFieldCell setStringValue:] + 150
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b215b1e -[NSControl setStringValue:] + 135
8   TeX Live Utility                    0x000000010e23741e -[TLMMainWindowController changeServerURL:] + 679
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b8dda43 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 312
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b38353f -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2f4c22 -[NSTextField textDidEndEditing:] + 545
12  TeX Live Utility                    0x000000010e2708b7 -[TLMAddressTextField textDidEndEditing:] + 103
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3dbce39c **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3dbce26a _CFXRegistrationPost + 458
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3dbcdfa1 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 225
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3db8cb32 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3db8bbc3 _CFXNotificationPost + 659
18  Foundation                          0x00007fff3fcba047 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b46943a -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _giveUpFirstResponder:] + 440
20  TeX Live Utility                    0x000000010e26f90c -[TLMMirrorFieldEditor insertNewline:] + 208
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2e1cff -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 200
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2e1c13 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) doCommandBySelector:completionHandler:] + 118
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c314e -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:] + 2898
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5ccbf __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.1109 + 360
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5caee __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 79
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2ca989 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 92
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5ca6d __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.1099 + 251
28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec8ace __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_5 + 70
29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec7986 ___ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec_block_invoke + 110
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb554cc __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.320 + 580
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c44df __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 79
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c4462 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 92
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c3fc5 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 1722
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c3895 _NSTSMEventHandler + 311
35  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3ce71904 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1541
36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3ce70c4d _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 374
37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3ce70ac3 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 45
38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec4bd9 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 389
39  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec50a4 __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 403
40  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec4f02 __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 219
41  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec4c28 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 468
42  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec4a27 SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 233
43  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec46e6 SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler + 290
44  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec449a __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 289
45  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec431b __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 405
46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec4108 TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 636
47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec3e4c __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4 + 262
48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec3c67 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 263
49  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec39a2 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 288
50  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec36f8 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 280
51  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3cec2cef TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler + 3433
52  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5c8e9 __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.1090 + 115
53  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5bcb7 __204-[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:]_block_invoke.1016 + 120
54  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5bb20 -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:] + 255
55  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5c32d -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:] + 1237
56  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bb5b9ad -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:allowingSyntheticEvent:] + 114
57  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c233d -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 209
58  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b2c215f -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 724
59  AppKit                              0x00007fff3ba7a43d -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5040
60  AppKit                              0x00007fff3ba78c70 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 497
61  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b8da236 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 2462
62  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b13a87d -[NSApplication run] + 812
63  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b109a3a NSApplicationMain + 804
64  TeX Live Utility                    0x000000010e22e12a main + 442
65  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff65bb1015 start + 1

Comment: Related question (answered): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628455/problem-installing-mactex2021-on-osx-10-13-6-high-sierra

Comment: This appears to be regarding TeX Live Utility, a GUI program that manages a TeX Live installation. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues and include the output from TLU's log window as a plain text attachment. I'm the maintainer, and need more info to resolve the problem. Offhand it sounds like an incomplete install.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by running TexDist-2021 once more.