# Latex does not run (2021 install on unsupported OSX version)

Tags: texlive-2021

I installed Tex2021 on MacOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) following the instructions on https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html for unsupported osx versions.

The install appears to have succeeded but latex no longer runs:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt: No such file or directory
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!

Related posts:

[Problem installing MacTex2021 on osx 10.13.6 (High Sierra)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628455/problem-installing-mactex2021-on-osx-10-13-6-high-sierra)

[TexLive fails with version mismatch message quoting version nr to be 2^64 - 1. Known bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628521/texlive-fails-with-version-mismatch-message-quoting-version-nr-to-be-264-1-k)

Comment: Did you follow all the information on that web page?

Comment: How were you trying to compile your tex file? Was it with a shell command, or through a programme?

Comment: I was installing compiled binaries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by running TexDist-2021 once more.